# Increasing the size of a minipage proportional to the contain

Tags: minipage, height

I am trying to create a simple environment. The enviroment contains a minipage that is surrounded but a dashed box.

```
\NewEnviron{Notes}{
  \par
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle,minimum width=0.95\textwidth] (m) {
      \begin{minipage} {0.75\textwidth}     
        \color{red}\BODY
      \end{minipage}
    };
    \draw[dashed] (m.south west) rectangle (m.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}\\
}
```

Essentially, I would like to increase the size of the box proportional to its contain. So, something like: `\vspace{0.2*\BODYHeight}`

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: the height of the box proportional to the height of its contain ? because the width is fixed 0.75\textwidth !

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Where does fixing the width present a problem for height?

Comment: a box has 2 dimensions : width and height. If a box is  proportional to another, height and width of the first  box must be proportional to the height and width of the second one and I'm not sure that you want. In my answer, only heights are proportional.. The width is fixed by 0.75 \textwidth .

Comment: A bad question, sorry. I meant that keeping the textwidth fixed and adjusting the height.

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is to enclose the `\BODY` with the necessary spacing. Here is a MWE.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\NewEnviron{Notes}{
  \par
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle,minimum width=0.95\textwidth] (m) {
      \begin{minipage} {0.75\textwidth}     
        \vspace*{0.1\textwidth}
        \color{red}\BODY
        \vspace{0.1\textwidth}
      \end{minipage}
    };
    \draw[dashed] (m.south west) rectangle (m.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}\\
}

\begin{Notes}
\lipsum[1]
\end{Notes}
\end{document}
```

A better approach is to rather use a fixed amount of padding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\NewEnviron{Notes}{
  \par
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle,minimum width=0.5\textwidth] (m) {
      \fbox{\begin{minipage} {0.5\textwidth}     
           \color{red}\BODY
       \end{minipage}}
    };
    \draw[dashed] (m.south west) rectangle (m.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}\\
}

\begin{Notes}
\lipsum[1]
\end{Notes}
\end{document}
```

if you add `\fboxsep0pt`, the inner rule will not be shown. Padding can be increased using a suitable value of `\fboxsep`. I think this is a much better solution in terms of typography and scales well. Non-linear scaling of the vertical spacing is also possible and one could employ a technique I first encountered in `amsgen`, `latex amsgen.dtx` and look up the definition of `\compute@ex@`. The difficulty is to find an acceptable formula to describe the aesthetics of such spacing. The formula should include for such variables as textwidth, height, font-size and the relationships to the rest of the text.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the gap isn't proportional to the amount of text in the environment. For example, `\begin{Notes}Test\end{Notes}` should only have a small gap around it.

Comment: @csgillespie Based on what formula? If the text is very large, it will yield a larger space? A better approach is to use a fixed amount of padding. I will expand in the post.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly proportional because eI added 2pt to avoid very small values  . It's possible to change `.05\htbox` with `.1\htbox`  but now the problem comes from big values.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document} 

\newbox\mybox 
\newdimen\htbox
\newdimen\innersep   
\NewEnviron{Notes}{%
 \setbox\mybox=\vbox{%
 \begin{minipage} {0.75\textwidth}     
   \color{red}\BODY
 \end{minipage}}% 
 \htbox\ht\mybox
 \advance\htbox by \dp\mybox
 \innersep=.05\htbox
 \advance\innersep by 2pt  
\par
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,inner sep=\innersep,rectangle,
      text width=0.95\textwidth-2\innersep] (m) {\unvcopy\mybox}; 
\end{tikzpicture}\\
}

\begin{Notes}
Texte
\end{Notes}

\begin{Notes}
\lipsum[1]
\end{Notes}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. See the additional notes in my answer regarding `proportional` spacing.

Comment: Yes I saw your comment and I agree with you, a fixed amount of padding is preferable but perhaps I don't understand the aim of the requirement about proportionality.

Comment: I am not sure either, but whatever it shouldn't be a linear function.